# CartoDB stripping the address from KML files

Tags: carto, kml, kmz

I am trying to import a kml file into CartoDB but everytime I do it seems to strip the address information.

Here is a sample of the KML file:

```
<Placemark>
            <styleUrl>#0</styleUrl>
            <name>AOJI Educ</name>              <ExtendedData>
                                            <Data name='Country'>
                            <value>Australia</value>
                        </Data>
                                            <Data name='Phone '>
                            <value>02 9264 7171</value>
                        </Data>
                                            <Data name='eMail'>
                            <value>aileen@globee.com</value>
                        </Data>
                                            <Data name='Website'>
                            <value>www.globee.com</value>
                        </Data>
                                            <Data name='Main Contact'>
                            <value>Ailen Wan</value>
                        </Data>
                                </ExtendedData>
                            <address>Suite 8, Level 6, 5961 George Street, Sydney New South Wales 2000 Australia</address>
            <Point>
                <coordinates>151.2058109,-33.8774203,0</coordinates>
            </Point>
        </Placemark>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CartoDB is using [ogr2ogr](http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html) to do the import so I'm afraid that's a limitation of that tool, I'd try to move that information inside the `ExtendedData` section.

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest you to convert the data into another format or in a correct schema that cartodb will accept before importing it into cartodb. FME would be best if you have access to one.